# How to bind p:selectBooleanCheckbox to a controller method

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to bind `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` to my controller method. I am getting below error when I try to bind. Is there any other way?

```
Property 'calculateBooleanValue' not found on type tr.controller.MyController
```

Here is my view

```
<p:datatable var="dataRow" ....>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myController.calculateBooleanValue(dataRow)}" />
```

MyController

```
public boolean calculateBooleanValue(Data data) {

 //There are some calculations with data and returns some boolean value acc. to this data


 }
```

Answer (score 8):

The `value` attribute must represent a value expression. I.e. it must be bound to a property which is represented by a true javabean getter and setter. You should not use method expression syntax with parentheses, this is not a valid value expression syntax.

Thus, so:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myController.booleanValue}" />
```

with

```
private boolean booleanValue;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    booleanValue = true;
}

public boolean isBooleanValue() {
    return booleanValue;
}

public void setBooleanValue(boolean booleanValue) {
    this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
}
```

If you intend to execute some "controller method" (as you call it yourself) on every click of the checkbox, then add a `<p:ajax>` with a listener:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myController.booleanValue}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{myController.changeBooleanValue}" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

with

```
public void changeBooleanValue() {
    System.out.println("Current boolean value is: " + booleanValue);
    // ... 
    // Do your job here.
}
```

Comment: I got it but my situation is a little different. I edited my question.

Comment: You should not attempt to perform business logic in getter methods. Just prepare exactly the model the view needs and let the view present it as is. In your case, you need `value="#{dataRow.booleanValue}"` which is already calculated for long before it's been set as bean property.

Comment: @BalusC If I recall correctly, you can use a method if you set "readonly" to true. Can you confirm that? I don't have a test bench right now.

Comment: @hellzone Yes, sorry, only `h:selectBooleanCheckBox` has it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `value` takes a [Value Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahv), not a [Method Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahz).

Think about it, how is the property going to be written, if it's a method?